# Latex editor solving math problems by cas

Tags: math-mode, lyx, emacs

Which Latex editor is capable to solve math problems really? Neither emacs nor Lyx do that though the relevant manuals say so. The menu in  Lyx offers to evaluate math expressions by maxima (Octave etc) but nothing happens. Emacs is not configurable by me. Does anyone knowif there is a solution?
Thanks,
Peter

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Your question appears to be about the capabilities of *editors* that are unrelated to their interfaces with TeX distributions. If this interpretation is correct, your query would be off-topic for this site. Please clarify. At the very least, please state which types of math problems you're expecting to solve in-editor.

Comment: In LyX if I put in math mode "2 + 2" and then right-click inside the math and go to "Use Computer Algebra System" and then "maxima", it turns into "2 + 2 = 4". It also works on more complicated expressions. Not sure if OS is an issue. Here I'm using Ubuntu.

Comment: This is not what happens with my Lyx. The only reaction is the = sign, but no output. Perhaps because I don´t use Linux? Or has maxima (wxmaxima) to be installed after Lyx?

Comment: I don't think maxima needs to be installed after LyX. Is there a `maxima` command in your PATH?

Comment: In Linux Mint: `sudo apt install maxima` then in LyX >Tools> Reconfigure> Restart. Alternatively, you can also install R and in LyX load the module `Sweave` or `Rnw(knitr)` [recommened] and then simply Insert>Custon Insets>S/R expression>2+2. In the edit window you will see only "2+2" in red but "4" in the PDF. It can be used also in text mode.

Comment: I do not know what "path" is in Win 10 pro. There is a link in the task line with the maxima command.
Sincerely Peter

Comment: wonderful! Addition of the path for ..Maxima>bin works: Lyx uses maxima.
Thanks for the hint,
Peter

Comment: the problem solved by additioning the correct path.+#